# How to code a general js function for all form submit events?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, form-submit

I want to code a single js/jquery function for all forms submit events in my application.

Currently I am hardcoding **on 3 locations** like that and it is working but I have to create a function for each form separately:

```
jQuery('#myForm').live('submit',function(event) { // #myForm hardcoded here
    $.ajax({
        url: 'one.php', // one.php hardcoded here
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#myForm').serialize(), // #myForm hardcoded here
        success: function( data ) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
jQuery('form').live('submit',function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function( data ) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

- You can probably replace $('#myForm') by $('form') or something else which matches all forms.
- one.php is probably the action attribute on the form, or $('form').attr('action').