# hiding login form with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, forms, hide

I created login from  that when clicking submit button sends variables to login_success.php page.but I want to make that when I click submit button login form will be close. I can close form using Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){
   $(".loginform").hide();
 });
});
</script>
```

But this time form does not sends request to .php file. I made it like addin script to .php file and then redirected to index.html site.It also good but I can see reflection.How can I combine them?

this is my form

```
<div class="loginform">
  <form action="php/login.php" method="post" id="login">

        <fieldset class="loginfield">
                    <div>
            <label for="username">User Name</label> <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="password">Password</label> <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
      <button type="submit" id="submit-go" ></button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Edit**
I used function as  NAVEED sad .I installed FireBug in firefox and I can see that my form validation works normal.It sends and request to login.php But I cant make any change on my form.It does not close or $arr values not shown on div tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [JSON](http://www.json.org/)/AJAX combination:

[Downlod jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

If your form look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>

<div id='errors'></div>
<div class='loginform' id='loginform'>
  <form action="php/login.php" method="post" id="login">
     Username:<input type="text" id="username" name="username">
     Password:<input type="password" id="password" name="password">
     <button type="submit" id="submit-go" value='Login'></button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Your jQuery Code in **ajax.js** file to submit the form and then get data from **'php/login.php**' in **JSON** and fill the required DIVs. If **login** is id of the form.

```
jQuery('#login').live('submit',function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/login.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('#login').serialize(),
        success: function( data ) {
            for(var id in data) {
                jQuery('#' + id).html(data[id]);
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

your **login.php** file as described in form action attribute:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if( $username and $password found in database ) {

  // It will replace only id='loginform' DIV content 
  // and login form will disappear
  $arr = array ( "loginform" => "you are logged in" ); 

} else {

  // It will replace only id='errors' DIV content
  $arr = array ( "errors" => "You are not authenticated. Please try again" );

}
echo json_encode( $arr );
```

**More Detail:**

- [How to submit a form in ajax/json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506272/php-problem-submitting-form-in-ajax-json):
- [General jquery function for all forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586610/how-to-code-a-general-js-function-for-all-form-submit-events)

Comment: I tried this but when I click submit nothing happens. For using ajax should I use some plug in or Jquery has its? And in form tag should I delete action = "php/login"  ?

Comment: You have to download jQuery and have to include it in your form file. If you have `action="php/login"` in your form tag then you can use `url: $(this).attr('action')` in `$.ajax` function. Look changes in answer.

Comment: May be you are missing something. Make sure your jquery file is included in your form file with correct path. If your jquery code is in separate file then make sure it is included in form file. Check the id of the form which is used in jquery to catch the event.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`submit` method](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

```
 $("button").click(function(){
   $("form.loginform").submit().hide();
 });
```

PS You do know that applying `onclick` handler to all `<button>` elements on the page is bad idea, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(".loginform").hide();
            return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: it closes logın form when I enter wrong pass or user name. If I enter ture login end password it redirect me to login_success.php How can I make it wise-verse ? or also when wrong it will only show on page that you are not registered.